# which queue exchange are using in RabbitMQ Web STOMP plugin

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

I am not sure but this are  rabbitmq stomp plugin exchange are used **/temp-queue, /exchange, /topic, /queue, /amq/queue, /reply-queue/**  . can you please explain the use of these each exchange.

Answer (score 4):

RabbitMQ docs about STOMP document these.

See our docs: https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html#d